# Gradle build-cache in composite builds

Tags: gradle, build, gitlab

I'm dealing with weird behavior using gradle ***build-cache*** with ***composite builds***.
I have a repo where i have 3 independent projects:

- app
- mocks
- integration-tests

Integration-tests are including 2 builds - mocks and app and starting both services as java apps (depending on jar task of both projects).

#### Running locally

When running locally, everything seems fine (also using build cache), but on integration machine, something weird is happening.

#### Integration testing

We use gitlab, and pipiline is quite simple:

```
---|-- junit-mocks --|--- integration-tests
   |-- junit-app ----|
```

junit mocks and junit app in parallel (with build cache) and next stage is int-testing where java compilation of app and mocks is loaded from build-cache. (as you can see in picture attached).

The error is only a consequence, that Main class was not found (weird#1). When i looked inside the jar file, it was truly half empty, missing a lot of classes, but static resources were there. When i looked into gradle's build/classes dir, it was completely empty. It's like cache was hit, but classes were not copied?

Weird#2: is that mocks has built successfully (and started), but not the app.

When I turned off build cache, build passed.

Any ideas what could cause the issue?

[image: Example of build]

Answer (score 0):

What type of gitlab executor/runner are you using?

Your cache is intended to be shared between gitlab stages however if you are using a docker executor, each stage will use a fresh docker image/environment so unless you are using artifacts, you would not be able to share a cache between them.

If you were using a shell executor which targets a specific machine on every build then you would be able to leverage a cache as long as it was not within the build directory because that changes on every gitlab stage in the pipeline.

Comment: To answer your question, I don't use docker image at all. Gradle cache is located in home directory of gitlab runner user (not within build). My problem is not that cache was not hit, but quite opposite. It seems like cache key is correct, but probably cache value is wrong and I'm curious how's that possible or what may cause this.